# Sencha Toch MVC - scripttag proxy - endless loading

Tags: model-view-controller, proxy, sencha-touch

The load of JsonDaten not work. It just shows the loading Notice

Model.js:

```
ps.models.Event = Ext.regModel("ps.models.Event", {
    fields: [
        {name: "id", type: "int"},
        {name: "date", type: "string"},
        {name: "kat", type: "string"},
        {name: "name", type: "string"},
        {name: "location", type: "string"},
    ]
});

ps.stores.event = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "ps.models.Event",
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url: 'http://www.asfdasdf.com/eventkalender/eventlist/format/json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

View.js:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'list',
    emptyText: 'Keine Events verfügbar',
    itemTpl: '{name}',
    //grouped: true,
    scroll: 'vertical',
    fullscreen: true,
    store: ps.stores.event
}
```

Whats wrong?

Thank you for your support!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is because of incorrect json format (you could check for errors by pressing CTRL+Shift+J in Chrome)
Try to follow this tutorial http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorial:Creating_JSON_Data_in_PHP

UPDATE

You need to add `root:'events'` to you proxy's reader:

```
ps.stores.event = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "ps.models.Event",
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url: 'http://www.asfdasdf.com/eventkalender/eventlist/format/json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'events'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Comment: Thats the response in JSON syntax:

    {
    "events": [
    {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2011-10-28 00:00:00",
    "kat": "Party",
    "name": "Testevent 1",
    "location": "asdf/ asdf"
    },
    {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2011-10-29 00:00:00",
    "kat": "Discothek",
    "name": "Testevent 2",
    "location": "asdf/ asf"
    }
    ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to account for any errors and timeouts with the below:

```
ps.stores.event = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "ps.models.Event",
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url: 'http://www.asfdasdf.com/eventkalender/eventlist/format/json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'events'
        },
        timeout: 3000, //milliseconds
        listeners: {
            exception:function(proxy, response){
                 console.error(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```